# Different results with/without breakpoint

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

In the controller of my .net core web application I have the following endpoint:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<BusAppl> BusinessApplications()
    {
        var temp = _context.BusAppl
            .Include(d=>d.BusApplDpndncyBusAppl)
            .Include(d=>d.BusApplDpndncyDepBusAppl);

        return temp;
    }
```

If I have a breakpoint on line `return temp;`, the `d.BusApplDpndncyDepBusApplproperty` (*the second Include*) seems to be included correctly. If I have no breakpoint it's null. It seems unlikely to me that this is the real problem, but this is how I am able to reproduce it 100% of the time.

If I `.ToList()` the whole result that forces it to be evaluated and seems to fix the issue, but should that be necessary?

What can be the issue here?

Comment: as queries in linq works on deferred execution concept  .ToList is helpful to get result of query immediatly i.e. it execute query and returns you result ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you have only a *selection* of data but no *projection*. You have to add e.g. `ToList()` or `ToArray()` to project (*execute*) the selection (*query*). It will cause the result's transformation into targeting type. If no result exists, it returns an empty list or array (targeting to examples above).
Well, in other words your [LINQ-to-Entities query](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/querying-entity-graph-in-entity-framework.aspx) will be converted into SQL and executed against server and retrieves the result.

If you add a `breakpoint` the query will be executed by VS under the hood too. Therefore you have no exception.

I'm not sure, but it seems to be that `Include` will be executed only on projection.

Nevertheless, if you will not modify a query (`IQueryable<T>`) and you want the result, you should execute it. Otherwise it could result in a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

As queries in linq works on deferred execution concept `.ToList()` is helpful to get result of query immediatly i.e. it execute query and returns you result.

If you want to return full result than you must use

```
var temp = (_context.BusAppl
            .Include(d=>d.BusApplDpndncyBusAppl)
            .Include(d=>d.BusApplDpndncyDepBusAppl)).ToList();
```

I havent worked on entity framework much , so cannot comment on breakpoint issue. may be its doing async operation